# How to prevent against path traversal attacks when using Class.getResource()

Tags: java, security, jar, static-resource

I am looking to provide users of my website access to some static resources which are provided within a JAR file.

I am unable to provide a list of all files which the user should be able to access, but I can ensure that they are all contained within a subdirectory of the JAR, e.g:

```
public-access/file-1
public-access/file-2
public-access/sub-dir/file-3
```

The files will then be accessed via:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/public-access/" + requestedFile);
```

Is there a recommended way to prevent path traversal attacks?  This is to prevent a malicious user from requesting a file called e.g. `../secret`, or `sub-dir/../../secret`

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this as well. Interestingly, I can't produce such an attack using "../" in the path. Perhaps it is being filtered away by Java somewhere in the process. Did you manage to perform the attack yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Security Manager: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html

I think it supports exactly what you need, just specify that opening a resource of given paths is not allowed.

Comment: It looks like I'd need to implement `checkRead()` in a custom security manager.  This would need to verify an instance of `FileDescriptor` to make sure that the absolute path requested is inside my allowed path.  Two issues with this - firstly I'd have to write the path resolution and verification functionality myself, which I expect has a lot of edge cases, and secondly there is one `SecurityManager` allowed per JVM, which means that I would have to restrict access through my whole application instead of solely in the `getResource()` call I am worried about, which seems less than ideal.

Comment: As above, you don't need to subclass `SecurityManager`. Should be able to write a policy file.

Comment: @Alison You're looking at the wrong overload(s) of `SecurityManager.checkRead`. / As you're calling a method on a type you cannot control the implementation of, you'll probably want to do any validation before calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to define a custom security policy by overriding  [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html).
Check this tutorial which nicely explains how to create one and register.

[Providing Your Own Security Manager](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/networking/security/index.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Same comment applies as per @Jakub above

Comment: You don't need to subclass `SecurityManager`. Should be able to write a policy file.